# Phalcon is not recognised as an internal command

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm trying to install phalcon for first time on Windows 8.1. I made the right config and I saw the phalcon ext in `phpinfo()`. Now I want to install the tools of phalcon.

I installed them as in the documentation page: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/wintools.html, but something is wrong. This should be the output:
[image]

And this is my output:
[image]

Is something wrong with that output?
Do I have to change something?
I can't even find a folder created by phalcon with models, controllers and views on my pc.
Does phalcon create a folder or do I have to create one by myself?

In the first tutorial it just says to create the files inside the controller or model or view folder, but where are these folders located?

Comment: did you write the phalcon bat file?

Comment: Yes i wrote the path in a phalcon.batch file

Comment: Did you added phalcon to path in env variables ?